# Send Session variable from Ajax to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I have 4 buttons on a page that each have their own button. When the button is clicked the page does not refresh nor does it open a new page.

When a button is pressed I want to send the ID of that button via Ajax to a php file in the form of a session. Each of the 4 buttons have a different ID (1,2,3,4). 
If a user clicks one button and then a second button etc, I want to add each of the clicked button Id's into this session.

This is what I have so far:

Jquery:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {  
     $('a[name=add]').click(function(e) {
     session = $(this).attr('id')

     $.post('sessions.php', {session:session}
    );              
     });
     });
```

So that simply checks if a button with the name of "add" has been clicked (all 4 of the buttons have that name), and grabs the buttons ID and sends it to sessions.php

PHP:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['ids'] = $_POST['session'];  
    ?>
```

Simply creates the session.

The problem I am having is that the PHP session is getting the ID of the first button clicked and that is all. If another button is clicked Ajax does post the button ID but the session only keeps the ID of the first button clicked.

How can I add the ID of the next buttons clicked to the session.

Example: If button 1 and 3 are clicked, I need the session to have ID 1 and 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
session_start();

// prepare $_SESSION['ids']
if ( ! is_array($_SESSION['ids']))
{
    $_SESSION['ids'] = array();
}

// fill $_SESSION['ids'] only with new $_POST['session'] posted
if ( ! in_array($_POST['session'], $_SESSION['ids']))
{
    $_SESSION['ids'][] = $_POST['session'];
}
```

Comment: How do I then get each individual value from the array so that I can search it in a MySQL database?

Comment: `foreach ($_SESSION['ids'] as $value) { /* use $value to search in DB */ }`

Comment: Thank you, however that only works if only 1 button is clicked (1 result in the array) if 2 buttons for example are clicked (2 id's stored in the session array) it does not work.

Comment: You must have problems with basic php. Take a deep look to [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) If you use my code as stated it must work... I recommend you firebug to debug AJAX posts...

Comment: Got it working, was just due to the ID's displaying as a single number, eg; 123, rather than 1, 2 ,3. Just did a quick implode to comma seperate them.

Comment: @IgorParra Parra - I came across this is a panic knee deep in my NGINX config / CORS / sub-domain session problems.. immediately fixed! THANK YOU. The solution was to dump the session_id into a DIV, and read it from the data property in jQuery - ```session: $.trim($('#session_id').text())``` then pick it up from the endpoint - ```trim($_GET['session'])```

Answer (score 2):

This is because Jquery treats name or id  as unique. Thats why your javascript function reads only first button.

**Solution:**

Use a **common class name** for the 4 buttons. (<a class="sessionclass otherclasses" href="#">1</a>)

Then change your jquery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {  
     $('a.sessionclass').click(function(e) {
         session = $(this).attr('id');    
         $.post('sessions.php', {session:session}
         );              
    });
});
```

Now your php session should set appropriate button value on click.

And I agree with @Lim H. Change your php code too like he suggested.

Comment: yeah this is a problem too. So OP needs to combine what OMG suggests and my solution.

Comment: OMG has the correct answer and for storing the session, you do not need an extra php script. just use `$.sessionStorage( 'foo', {data:'bar'} );` in your jQuery script...+1

Comment: Even though your solution is nicer than the initial code, this is not true jQuery doesn't treat name as unique : http://jsfiddle.net/gZZCs/

Comment: @roy-finley  `sessionStorage` is `HTML5` functionality. Not good for compatibility. @OMG: `$('a[name=add]')` is correct as OP use `$(this)` to get their `id`.

Comment: @NomikOS I think what OMG meant is that name has to be unique in Javascript so $('a[name=add]') should match only one element instead of 4. But come to think of it, I think it's not true.

Comment: @lim-h You can have the same element's name in several forms in the same page. Totally legal... `$('a[name=add]')` is right :)

Comment: @NomikOS Thanks for the $.sessionStorage logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $id = $_POST['session']);
    if(!isset($_SESSION['ids'])) {
        $_SESSION['ids']= array();         
    }

    $_SESSION['ids'][$id] = $_POST['session']';
?>
```

Every time the AJAX request is made, your session id got reinitialized, hence in the end only one value remains. So you may want to create an array for session ids and every new id value get inserted into this array.