# unable to make ajax work to send form data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

i am unable to see what is wrong with the below code. I simply want to submit a php variable to another php page. please don't say sessions as i know for sure sessions wont work for me here. all i want is to send the session variable to the next php page via ajax and without the user knowing it.

```
        <?php
        session_start();
        $fname=$_SESSION['mail'];
        ?>

        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
        <title>Addressbook</title>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>





 <script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){


$.ajax({
     url:"DbManipulate.php",
              type:"POST",
              data:"source1:"<?php echo $fname ?>""

               });

}

 </script>          
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="crudstyle.css" />

        </head>
        <body>

            <div id="hidden_form_container" style="display:none;"></div>

        <div id="mhead"><h2>Your Adressbook</h2></div>
        <div id="note"> <span> your addressbook is connected to our servers :) </span></div>
        <?php
        echo $fname;

        ?>
        <table id='demoajax' cellspacing="0">
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350346/send-session-variable-from-ajax-to-php

Comment: try `'source1:"<?php echo $fname ?>"'`

Answer (score 0):

Passing `data` as a `object` is not correct in your code. Please change as follows and try

```
data:{source1:"<?php echo $fname ?>"}
```

Comment: and then can i access source1 as a posted data? like $POST["source1"]

Comment: yes ofcourse! you can get using $_POST["source1"] ...you missed _ in your previous comment.

Comment: tried as you said no use. i retrieved using $POST_["source1"] and echoed it in the php page. But i didnt get any output.

Comment: Could you please track the request using firebug or clicking F12 in chrome and see the network tab...

Answer (score 0):

There is some syntax error in your `data:value` part in **[`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)** call

You should use

```
data: "source1=<? php echo $fname ?>"
```

or

```
data:{source1:"<? php echo $fname ?>"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       <?php
        session_start();
        $fname="surat";
        ?>

        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
        <title>Addressbook</title>
        <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>





 <script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

var sessioni='<?php echo $fname ?>';
$.ajax({
     url:"DbManipulate.php",
              type:"POST",
              data:{source1:sessioni}

               });

});

 </script>          
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="crudstyle.css" />

        </head>
        <body>

            <div id="hidden_form_container" style="display:none;"></div>

        <div id="mhead"><h2>Your Adressbook</h2></div>
        <div id="note"> <span> your addressbook is connected to our servers :) </span></div>
        <?php
        echo $fname;

        ?>
        <table id='demoajax' cellspacing="0">
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

        </body>
        </html>
```